# ASP.Net Web Application Deployment to IIS Error Authenticate is not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have built a Web Application in ASP.net MVC on my local machine. And it runs correctly and has no issues.

Now when I publish it into a Web Deploy package and then run the installer on the IIS server it installs correctly. Then when I browse to the site the login page allows me to login and everything. But as soon as I try to access a page that requires my SQL connection. I get this error. And I have not been able to figure it out.

```
Server Error in '/SPBCyberSecurity' Application.

Keyword not supported: 'authentication'. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'authentication'.

Source Error: 


[ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'authentication'.]
   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey) +6667870
   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules) +134
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString) +103
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous) +35
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions) +294
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key) +60
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value) +89
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +207
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.SetConnectionString(DbConnection connection, DbConnectionPropertyInterceptionContext`1 interceptionContext) +438
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String newConnectionString) +900

[EntityException: The underlying provider failed on ConnectionString.]
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String newConnectionString) +1305
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.InitializeFromConnectionStringSetting(ConnectionStringSettings appConfigConnection) +161
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig(String name, AppConfig config) +46
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize() +95
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel() +16
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() +340
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ObjectContext() +21
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ExecuteSqlQuery(String sql, Nullable`1 streaming, Object[] parameters) +124
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ExecuteSqlQueryAsIEnumerator(String sql, Nullable`1 streaming, Object[] parameters) +92
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ExecuteSqlQuery(Type elementType, String sql, Nullable`1 streaming, Object[] parameters) +255
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalSqlNonSetQuery.GetEnumerator() +44
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbRawSqlQuery`1.GetEnumerator() +48
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +446
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +80
   CyberSecurity.Controllers.OverviewClass.getVulnOverview(String theDate) +347
   CyberSecurity.Controllers.HomeController.Dashboard() +102
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +79
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +242
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +112
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +452
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +241
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +111
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +19
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +51
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +111
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
```

Connection String generated by Publish to web config package

```
<setParameter name="VulnDBEntities-Web.config Connection String" value="metadata=res://*/VulnsModel.csdl|res://*/VulnsModel.ssdl|res://*/VulnsModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='Data Source=devsrv47;Initial Catalog=VulnDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=***********;Password=****************;Authentication=&quot;Active Directory Password&quot;'" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you've posted, it looks like you've used the word "authentication" in your connection string, which is not supported.

Comment: It works on my local machine. And the connection string was generated by Visual Studio. So why wouldn't it work on my IIS server. That is so confusing to me

Comment: They could be using different versions of the connection driver, or the server that it is connecting to has been configured to reject that command.

Comment: I added the connection string that is generated by VS

Comment: Alright I will try and look into my configs on that server

Comment: Try removing the "Authentication=&quot;Active Directory Password&quot;" and testing that locally. Then test on the server.

Comment: Without that, it tries to use my creds on the SQL server it's self

Comment: You put me down the right path. Now everything is working correctly. I changed how my application pool was setup and removed my creds for the web config